# IntelliJ Idea 12 render error with ui builder android

Tags: android, intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea 12's android UI builder is giving render error every time I drag and drop a `Switch` to the `Layout`.Every other widget is working fine.Is this a bug.If yes,any work around?

[image]

update: Here's the link for error image - https://www.dropbox.com/s/d09xfm8c0l6omlb/Untitled.png

Comment: What's in the the log?  Google for where IDEA stores it's logs on your OS.  The log usually has a full stack trace for the error.

Comment: Errors are right there on top left of preview screen in text mode. Click on them to see what went wrong.

Comment: I've attached the image.I suppose it isn't properly visible.I'll provide a link soon.

Comment: It's a shame that one spends a lot of time fixing one problem or the other in these IDEs (Intellij ,Android Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you didn't select a `Theme` and is not specific to IDEA. I'm pretty sure you will have the same error with eclipse ADT.

As a *workaround*: select a theme.

Comment: One more question which doesn't relate to the above.R.java is completely empty unlike eclipse(ADT) where it contains every reference.What to do?Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Just select the theme like the screenshot and it will render correctly

[image]